# How to create pattern brush using PNG image

Tags: c++, mfc

I have image with black dots in a white background, which i use to create a patten brush and change the color of the black dots using SetTextColor. So I created a CBitmap using PNG image(i used CPngImage to get HBITMAP and attached it to CBitmap ). Now i created PatternBrush using(CreatePatternBrush) with that bitmap, the problem is that the color of the brush doesn't change if i use PNG image. But it changes when i use image in bmp format.

here is some code

```
CBitmap bmp;
if (bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1))
{
   if (brush.CreatePatternBrush(&bmp))
   pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
}

pDC->SetTextColor(color);
```

This Works

```
 CBitmap bmp;
    CPngImage pngImage;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

    if ( pngImage.Load(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1)) )
    {
       hBitmap = (HBITMAP)pngImage.Detach();
    }


    if ( hBitmap )
      bmp.Attach(hBitmap);

    if (brush.CreatePatternBrush(&bmp))
      pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brush);

    pDC->SetTextColor(color);
```

This Doesn't work

Comment: Let's see some code.

Comment: CBitmap bmp;
 if (bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1))
 {
  if (brush.CreatePatternBrush(&bmp))
   pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
 }

 pDC->SetTextColor(color);  This Works

Comment: CBitmap bmp;
CPngImage pngImage;
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

 if ( pngImage.Load(MAKEINTRESOURCE(nIDResource)) )
 {
  hBitmap = (HBITMAP)pngImage.Detach();
 }
 
 
 if ( hBitmap )
  bmp.Attach(hBitmap);
  
 if (brush.CreatePatternBrush(&bmp))
   pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
 
 pDC->SetTextColor(color); This Doesn't work

Comment: @RaviTeja don'tm post code in comments (it's unreadable) but [edit] your question and put your code _there_ and format it correctly.

Comment: I was bored so I created a proper **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, but I couldn't duplicate the problem which you are describing. I had to take some guesses to fill the parts you had left out. MCVE should be your job because you are the one asking the question!

Comment: By the way, which version of Visual Studio are you using? `CPngImage` is derived from `CBitmap`, it already has `HBITMAP` object, you can use it directly in `CreatePatternBrush`